# Is it possible to migrate Sharepoint 2016 and all it's databases from SQL SERVER2012 to AZURE?

Tags: sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database, sharepoint

we are in a process to migrate our website to azure.

we have those tons of sharepoint databases :

[image]

Is it possible to migrate all user databases + sharepoint to azure?

I could migrate some user databases to azure with no problem in the past ( bkp as data tier, and etc and etc ) but I've never done this with sharepoint databases.

I could found some questions saying it's not possible.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241759/sharepoint-2013-on-azure-with-on-premise-sql-server
It says "ou cannot move to a Azure SQL Database".

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217477/sharepoint-migration-of-db-from-one-server-to-another-server
This one is from on premises to on premises.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/archive/blogs/sambetts/hosting-sharepoint-content-databases-in-sql-azure
"Important edit: this is currently not officially supported for SharePoint Server, even for Azure-hosted farms."

and then with all those questions and answers, I dont know how to proceeed.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes.

Should you? [Documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/archive/blogs/sambetts/hosting-sharepoint-content-databases-in-sql-azure)...

> Important edit: **this is currently not officially supported for
>   SharePoint Server**, even for Azure-hosted farms. This is likely due to
>   the 1-millisecond SharePoint -> SQL supportability requirement which
>   Azure SQL Database doesn't & won't guarantee. At the time of writing
>   there's no plans to do so either, so please note that **despite the fact
>   this configuration by all accounts does work, this article is purely
>   academic.**

No.